# Shortcut for centering the horizontal scroll bar in a browser

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

I saw in a previous thread that this JS can be used to center a horizontal scroll bar:

```
document.body.scrollLeft = (document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.clientWidth) / 2
```

Is there a way to bind that to a keyboard shortcut to execute on any webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [keymaster.js](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) to bind keyboard shortcuts to webpage. It will make things very simple.

`key('a', function(){ alert('you pressed a!') });`